# "Unable to create a new session" while running the parallel execution in AndroidDriver using ThreadLocal class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

**Aim :** Working on parallel execution of test classes on different devices

**Implementation brief:** I have created BaseClass in which capabilties are defined & android driver instance created. Apart from that there is one DriverFactory class which has implementation of thread local object, set & get methods and in testng.xml: we have defined parameters like udid, url, platformName

**Code:**
**BaseClass capabilities:**

```
                // capabilities to run locally
                try {
                    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT, 60);
                    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", prop.getProperty("androidAppPackage"));
                    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", prop.getProperty("androidAppActivity"));
                    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, udid);
                    log.info("DeviceUdid: " + udid);
                    capabilities.setCapability("app", mApkfilepath);
                    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, platformName);
                 capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
                capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
                capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "15");
                capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", true);
                capabilities.setCapability("noReset", false);
                driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(url), capabilities); // exception "Session not created" at this line"
                System.out.println("Driver: " + driver);
                //return driver;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return driver;
```

**DriverFactory Class:**

```
        private static DriverFactory instance = null;
        private static ThreadLocal<AndroidDriver<MobileElement>> tdriver = new ThreadLocal<AndroidDriver<MobileElement>>();
        // thread local driver object for android driver

        private DriverFactory() {

        }

        public static DriverFactory getInstatnce() {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new DriverFactory();
            return instance;
        }

        // call this method to set the driver object
        public void setDriver(AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver) {
            tdriver.set(driver);
        }

        // call this method to get the driver object & launch the app
        public AndroidDriver<MobileElement> getDriver() {
            return tdriver.get();
        }

        // call this method to remove the driver
        public void removeDriver() {
            tdriver.get().quit();
            tdriver.remove();
        }
```

**TestClass:**
    public class HomePageTest extends BaseClass {

```
    public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    HomePage homePage;

    public HomePageTest() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({ "platformName", "url" ,"udid" })
    public void prepareTest(String platformName, String url, String udid) throws Exception {
        try {
            driver = BaseClass.createInstance(platformName, url , udid);
            DriverFactory.getInstatnce().setDriver(driver);
            driver = DriverFactory.getInstatnce().getDriver();
            homePage = new HomePage(driver);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: - It runs fine on single device but getting exception of unable to create session

Comment: While running the test in parallel, sometimes it takes udid of the one device and run in both the appium server (having different port) which results in skipp all the testcases  . Please look into the code  & do let me know where i am missing

Comment: To run parallel test you need to run appium server in different ports(each appium server for a device), provide udid of each device and specify to run that device in specific appium server port. You also need multiple device for that